# Installing QT5 with online installer on fresh ubuntu system

Tags: software-installation, qt5

After downloading the open source file (qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run) the start ends with "�HD@Xn@8 (invalid encoding)". I'm on a new installed ubuntu (Jetson nano). This is also the first Software I want to install. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem could be that the software is not meant to be used on ARM-processors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415291/3128341

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, what Ubuntu product did you download from ubuntu.com and install?